# Zend Gdata Spreadsheet not feeding cells if empty at the beginning of the sheet

Tags: php, excel, zend-framework, gdata

i've got a little problem linking my Google Drive Spreadsheet with my php page. 
I'm using Zend Gdata libraries.
this is the code I am using:

```
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_CellQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($key);
$cellFeed = $spreadSheetService->getCellFeed($query);
   $foglio=array();
foreach($cellFeed as $cellEntry) {
  $row = $cellEntry->cell->getRow();
  $col = $cellEntry->cell->getColumn();
  $val = $cellEntry->cell->getText();
  $foglio[$row][$col]=$val;
}
```

And it's all ok but one thing.. when the code encounter a row without values nea the start... it just skips to feed those values.. for example:
here i have my values long to the end of document.. over 45-50 cols and the program just skips them in the getCellFeed.. giving me error when i try access them

[Image 01](http://oi58.tinypic.com/1z65zcz.jpg)

if i write something in a cell near the start like the image below, instead, the program works perfectly... but i dont want to ruin my spreadsheet with random number or characters just to fix the problem, suggestions?

[Image 02](http://oi59.tinypic.com/k477o1.jpg)

Comment: Nothing to do with apps-script. Remove tag

Answer (score 0):

This is by-design. Cell feeds do not return array-array formatted data, use a row feed instead (but that one stops on the first blank row)
You need to post-process your array to fill in missing rows and columns, or handle the missing entries case when using the array.